# Como puedo lanzar un intent pulsando en el elemento hijo de una expansible List?

Tags: android

Quiero lanzar un intent pero me da un error y no localizo el porque. Alguna sugerencia. Me da el error al crear el intent:

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dato = tempChild.get(childPosition);
            Toast.makeText(activity, dato,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewAdapter.this, Ficha.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

NewAdapter.java es una clase que extiende de BaseExpandableListAdapter.

Comment: Una pregunta, en tu clase tienes el método: public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) { ?

Comment: si lo tengo, ya esta listo. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás utilizando como contexto del intent el adaptador. Supongo que 'activity' es la actividad desde donde se llama al adaptador por tanto quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Ficha.class);
intent.putExtra("id", id);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: ok ya lo entendi gracias solucionado

Answer (score 2):

Lo que se necesita definitivamente es el contexto de la Actividad :

```
//Intent intent = new Intent(NewAdapter.this, Ficha.class);
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Ficha.class);
intent.putExtra("id", id);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

pero es importante mencionar que para realizar esto, ya que se realiza dentro de una clase que extiende de `BaseExpandableListAdapter` :

```
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
```

**se necesita un método que reciba el contexto y ese método es `setInflater()`:**

```
public Activity activity;

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
    this.minflater = mInflater;
    activity = act;
}
```

La clase debe recibir el contexto de alguna forma para usarlo en el `Intent`.

Comment: Si lo tengo ya listo. Gracias.

Comment: Lo agregué porque agregar solo : Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Ficha.class); no funcionaría si no obtienes el contexto de la actividad en la clase Adapter.